# Online Judgement System - Why am I getting Wrong Answer for this thread?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Original page: http://acm.whu.edu.cn/learn/problem/detail?problem_id=1036

This should be a simple Dynamic Programming problem. I figured out the solution to be the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    double d[501];
    int i;
    d[0] = d[1] = 1.;
    d[2] = 2.;
    for(i = 3; i<=500; i++)
        d[i] = d[i-1] + d[i-2] + d[i-3];


    int n;
    while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        if(n == 0) return 0;
        printf("%.0lf\n", d[n]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But Wrong Answer reported after submission. I really don't know why.

Comment: OJ? WA? DP? WTPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double is not enough for the precision

you should use high-precision to solve it

Comment: double is more than enough

Comment: @UmNyobe Can you tell why did I get Wrong Answer?

Comment: How is high-precision implemented?

Comment: @UmNyobe For 500 cards, there are `1306186569702186634983475450062372018715120191391192207156664343051610913971927959744519676992404852130396504615663042713312314219527` ways. `double` isn't enough.

Comment: my mistake. `3^(n/3)d[0] < d[n] < 3^(n) d[2]`. Indeed, `3^(166)` is big.

Comment: Yes, double is enough but not precise. So I tried high-precision and passed. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Decimal point maybe. `printf("%.0lf\n", 1.0);` will print `1.0` but system may wait for `1`.

Comment: Definitely the first thing to check. The system ***is*** waiting for decimal numbers, no floating point numbers